# Convert many string with separator to array in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this :

```
userId    someString      varA     varB
   1      "example1"    0,2,5     1,2,9
   2      "example2"    1,20,5   9,null,6
```

i want to convert the data into VarA and varB to an array of String

```
userId    someString      varA     varB
   1      "example1"    [0,2,5]   [1,2,9]
   2      "example2"    [1,20,5]  [9,null,6]
```

Comment: If varA and varB is a string, then simply do str.split(",")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its fairly Simple. you can use sql split function.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
df.withColumn("varA", split($"varA",",")).withColumn("varB", split($"varB",",")).show()
```

**Output**

```
+------+----------+----------+------------+
|userId|someString|      varA|        varB|
+------+----------+----------+------------+
|     1|  example1| [0, 2, 5]|   [1, 2, 9]|
|     2|  example2|[1, 20, 5]|[9, null, 6]|
+------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: @RadhwenKHADHRI Happy to help :)